# How to get limited amount of recent posts in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am a DJANGO beginner and I am making a biography app as my first project. I want my homepage to show a limited number of recent posts. I am providing my Django files so you'll look up and help me with this problem. Thanks

```
#views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from .models import About

# Create your views here.

class Home(ListView):
    """docstring for Home"""
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = About
    recents = About.objects.all()
    for recent in recents:
        if recent.was_published_recently():
            print (recent.id)


class BiographyDetail(DetailView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""
    model = About
    template_name = 'details.html'


class About(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'about.html'
    model = About


class Contacts(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'contact.html'
    model = About


class Projects(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'projects.html'
    model = About


class Search(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'search.html'
    model = About
```

#models.py I have defined a function was_published_recently which tells whether any posts was published in that certain interval as you can figure that out by its name

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.

TYPE = (
    ('politician','POLITICIAN'),
    ('poet','POET'),
    ('author','AUTHOR'),
    ('actor','ACTOR'),
    )



class About(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    quote = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    born = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Born on', null = True)
    born_at = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    died = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Died on', null = True)
    died_at = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    main = models.TextField(default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices = TYPE , default = 'poet', max_length = 10)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='', upload_to='static')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.created_on >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=15)
```

## home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Header Starts -->
    <header style="background-color: black;">
        <div class="container">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" >

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}" style="color: white; font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif; font-weight: 800;">J<span style="color: red;">O</span>URNEY</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class="bi bi-filter-left" width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 10.5a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h3a.5.5 0 010 1h-3a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h7a.5.5 0 010 1h-7a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h11a.5.5 0 010 1h-11a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>               
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{%  url 'about' %}" class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'contact'%}" class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'projects' %}" class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Search</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
    </header> 
    <!-- Header Ends -->


    <!-- Search -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-12">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <div class="card card-body" style="background-color: black; border-radius: 0px;">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary search-button" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                                        <a href="{% url 'search' %}"><svg class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 011.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                             <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 100-11 5.5 5.5 0 000 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 11-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0113 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                        </svg></a>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div><!-- Search -->

#this is where I am using for loop for recents

    <!-- Main Starts -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-12">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            {% for about in object_list %}
                                {% load static %}

                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12" >
                                    <a href="{% url 'details' about.id  %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                        <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                            <img src="{{about.image.url}}" height="260" width="auto">
                                                <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center; background-color: black; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                    <h1 class="card-text" style="font-size: 17px; color: white; font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;">{{ about.name}}</h1>

                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
                <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                    <h4 style="margin-top: 20px; text-decoration: underline; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;" >Recent Posts</h4>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">                                       
                        <ul style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">
                            {% for post in recents %}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;">
                                        <h6>
                                            {{ recent.name }}
                                        </h6>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>                                                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Ends -->

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the results of the query

```
recents = About.objects.all()[:10]
```

Comment: You create a loop:
{% for post in recents %}
   {{ ... }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: I did that but it is not showing, I have provided my HTML code

Comment: better read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/